# display cat result in MB

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal

Is there a way to display the returned result `cat /sys/class/net/wlan0/statistics/rx_bytes` in MB (Megabytes) instead of bytes.

Thanx for any advice;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the command `expr` as follows:

```
# expr $(cat /sys/class/net/wlan0/statistics/rx_bytes) / 1024 / 1024
```

Edit:
Since `expr` is for integers only you can use `bc` for floating point numbers as follows:

```
# echo "$(cat /sys/class/net/wlan0/statistics/rx_bytes) / 1024 / 1024" | bc -l
```